# store big data with best searching time

Tags: data-structures

I need to store data with fast searching and insertion and deletion ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use hashtable with O(1) time deletion searching and insertion.
checking out basic stuff with java
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashtable-in-java/